# FlexSlider Messing In Firefox 26

Tags: jquery, html, css, flexslider

i am using FlexSlider v2.0 - Slider w/thumbnail slider . It Was Working Fine In All Browser But It Is Crashed In Firefox 26. Even It Is Still Working Good In IE9 & IE8, Chrome & Safari.Below is The Markup

```
<!-- FlexSlider --> 
    <script defer src="js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /*$(function(){
            SyntaxHighlighter.all();
        });*/
        $(window).load(function(){
            $('#carousel').flexslider({
                animation: "slide",
                controlNav: false,
                animationLoop: false,
                slideshow: false,
                itemWidth: 195,
                itemMargin: 5,
                asNavFor: '#slider'
            });

            $('#slider').flexslider({
                animation: "slide",
                controlNav: false,
                animationLoop: false,
                slideshow: false,
                sync: "#carousel",
                start: function(slider){
                    $('body').removeClass('loading');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>


    <div id="carousel" class="flexslider">
        <ul class="slides">
           ....
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Check Link http://www.unoapp.com

The issue is like ::
[image]

Comment: I'm up to date with FireFox and it's 25.01. 26 is not shipped yet. Your slider works with latest FireFox.

Comment: @cab *"First offered to release channel users on December 10, 2013"* -  http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/26.0/releasenotes/